# Show that for all $r \geq 1$ it is $A_{r-1} \subset D_r \subset A_r$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Define for $r \geq 0$ the sets $D_r=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2 \ \text{s.t.} \ x \geq 0, \ 0 \leq y \leq 1, \ x^2+y^2 \leq r^2\}$ and $A_r=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2 \ \text{s.t.} \ 0 \leq x \leq r, \ 0 \leq y \leq 1\}$.
Show that for all $r \geq 1$ it is $A_{r-1} \subset D_r \subset A_r$.

My approach is the following: for proving that $A \subset B$ I need to prove that $\forall p :(p\in A \Rightarrow p\in B)$. So let $(x,y)\in A_{r-1}$, I think that I have to prove that both the coordinates of a point in the contained set satisfy the inequalities of the coordinates of the points in the set that contains. Since all the three sets have the bound $0 \leq y \leq 1$, I only have to show the implication of the $x$ coordinate.

$D_r \subset A_r$: Since $0 \leq x^2 + y^2 \leq r^2$ it follows that $ x^2 \leq r^2$ and since by hypothesis $r \geq 0$ it follows that $0 \leq x \leq r$.

$A_{r-1} \subset D_r$: Here too the only condition on $x$ given by $D_r$ is that $0 \leq x \leq r$. By definition of $A_{r-1}$ it is $0 \leq x \leq r-1$, so since $r-1 \leq r$ it follows that $0 \leq x \leq r-1 \leq r \Rightarrow x \leq r$; the only added condition here is that $0 \leq x \leq r-1 \Rightarrow 0 \leq r-1 \Rightarrow r \geq 1$.

I'm not sure if this is how I should proceed. Thanks.

Comment: Your proof of $A_{r-1} \subset D_r$ is incorrect. What you have to proof is that if $0 \leq x \leq r-1$ and $0 \leq y \leq 1$, then $x^2 + y^2 \leq r^2$... You cannot evacuate the condition on $y$.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe: Thanks for your comment, maybe something like this? Since $0 \leq y \leq 1$ and if $r \geq 1$ it is $r-1 \geq 0$ it is $x^2+y^2 \leq (r-1)^2 +1$ and this is true if $r \geq 1$.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe: Sorry I forgot to say $(r-1)^2+1 \leq r^2$! And then this is true for $r \geq 1$. Thanks! Do you confirm that $D_r \subset A_r$ is correct? So in general, when I'm proving these kind of inclusions, I have to check all the "hidden" conditions that could emerge, like $x^2+y^2 \leq r^2 \Rightarrow y^2 \leq r^2$?

Comment: Yes, your $D_r \subset A_r$ was correct. In general, you just have to check whether, assuming the conditions of belonging to the first set, all the conditions of belonging to the second one are satisfied...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write it in a more direct way.

If $(x,y) \in A_{r-1}$, then $0 \leq x \leq r-1$ and $0 \leq y \leq 1$, so $0 \leq x^2 \leq (r-1)^2$ and $0 \leq y^2 \leq 1$. Adding these inequalities together, you get $x^2 + y^2 \leq (r-1)^2+1 = r^2 +2(1-r) \leq r^2$  because $r \geq 1$. The two other conditions $x \geq 0$ and $0 \leq y \leq 1$ are also satisfied, so $(x,y) \in D_r$.

If $(x,y) \in D_r$, then $x \geq 0$ and $0 \leq y \leq 1$, and $x^2 + y^2 \leq r^2$. So $x^2 \leq r^2-y^2 \leq r^2$, and because $x \geq 0$, you deduce that $0 \leq x \leq r$. Because the condition $0 \leq y \leq 1$ is also satisfied, you have $(x,y) \in A_r$.